# jointed body not following the real body

Tags: android, ios, iphone, box2d, andengine

I use this two body jointed. Player body and his foot body.But footBody don't follow player body.?

```
  final FixtureDef fixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0, 0, 0.1f);
    this.body = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, this, BodyType.DynamicBody, fixtureDef);
    this.body.setUserData("player");
    this.body.setFixedRotation(true);
    this.mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(this, this.body, true, true));
    this.setCurrentTileIndex(8); //Başlangıç resmi

    this.foot = new Rectangle(this.getX()-20, this.getY(), 10, 50);

    final FixtureDef footFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0, 0, 0, true);
    footFixtureDef.isSensor = true;
    this.footBody=PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, this.foot, BodyType.DynamicBody, footFixtureDef);
    this.footBody.setUserData("foot");
    this.foot.setColor(0.9f, 0.3f, 0.6f);

    this.mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(this.foot, this.footBody, true, true));

     final WeldJointDef joint = new WeldJointDef();
     joint.initialize(this.body, this.footBody, this.body.getWorldCenter());
     this.mPhysicsWorld.createJoint(joint);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 10 questions for a 10min, and every one of them are - two words and a big block of code with no clear definition. Nobody will answer you if you don't modify the questions.